# Explain in a more descriptive way what is happening here - advanced lifetime example in rust-by-practice - "A difficult exercise"

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am learning rust with TRPL book. Got the basic idea of borrow checker/ lifetime concepts. Now solving [exercism](https://exercism.org/) problems and trying out other smaller exercises to improve. As like many others, lifetime seems to be tougher one to conquer.

The below life time example in "Rust-by-practice" book seems very interesting one and not able comprehend it well (the solution is to use two lifetimes, which is available there itself)   (https://practice.rs/lifetime/advance.html#a-difficult-exercise)

```
/* Make it work */
struct Interface<'a> {
    manager: &'a mut Manager<'a>
}

impl<'a> Interface<'a> {
    pub fn noop(self) {
        println!("interface consumed");
    }
}

struct Manager<'a> {
    text: &'a str
}

struct List<'a> {
    manager: Manager<'a>,
}

impl<'a> List<'a> {
    pub fn get_interface(&'a mut self) -> Interface {
        Interface {
            manager: &mut self.manager
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = List {
        manager: Manager {
            text: "hello"
        }
    };

    list.get_interface().noop();

    println!("Interface should be dropped here and the borrow released");

    use_list(&list);
}

fn use_list(list: &List) {
    println!("{}", list.manager.text);
}
```

Compiler yells on above code, which gives an impression of borrow checker met a forbidden access (in fact,it should be, I guess). However the solution is a surprise! Use of two lifetimes. I would think, at a high level, this might be an effect of non-lexical-lifetime of rustc, though not sure.

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `list` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:39:14
   |
35 |     list.get_interface().noop();
   |     ---- mutable borrow occurs here
...
39 |     use_list(&list);
   |              ^^^^^
   |              |
   |              immutable borrow occurs here
   |              mutable borrow later used here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to previous error
```

The solution for this exercise is here.

[solution link](https://github.com/sunface/rust-by-practice/blob/master/solutions/lifetime/advance.md)

```
struct Interface<'b, 'a: 'b> {
    manager: &'b mut Manager<'a>
}

impl<'b, 'a: 'b> Interface<'b, 'a> {
    pub fn noop(self) {
        println!("interface consumed");
    }
}

struct Manager<'a> {
    text: &'a str
}

struct List<'a> {
    manager: Manager<'a>,
}

impl<'a> List<'a> {
    pub fn get_interface<'b>(&'b mut self) -> Interface<'b, 'a>
    where 'a: 'b {
        Interface {
            manager: &mut self.manager
        }
    }
}

fn main() {

    let mut list = List {
        manager: Manager {
            text: "hello"
        }
    };

    list.get_interface().noop();

    println!("Interface should be dropped here and the borrow released");

    use_list(&list);
}

fn use_list(list: &List) {
    println!("{}", list.manager.text);
}
```

Can some one explain how this lifetime changes made the compiler to allow code w.r.t to errors spit earlier, in a little more explicit way?

Comment: I removed the off-topic part, hoping its closed for that and re-phrased the question.